# How to hide a file in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I have a really huge webpack compiled javascript file in my project, and I'd like for it to be hidden in Atom since I keep clicking on it by accident, making Atom freeze.

How do I hide specific files in Github Atom Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to hide a file would be to add it to the ignore-list in settings (open preferences, go to settings, under `Core Settings` you'll find `Ignored Names`).
Then to hide those from the tree view go to Packages, search for `tree-view`, open it's settings and make sure that `Hide Ignored Names` is checked.

If you're using a `git`-repository, for example, and don't need the file to be checked into the repository, it'd be cleaner to just add the file to  `.gitignore`. Atom respects git-ignores and also hides them from the tree-view (as long as `Hide VCS Ignored Names` in the `tree-view`-settings is enabled).